# FFmpeg poor quality encoded MPEG-4 video

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec

Have adapted FFmpeg sample muxing.c under Windows 7 to write MP4 files from video camera RGB data.
Using muxing.c default bit_rate=400000.
Am not setting global_quality.
Resultant MP4 is poor quality, highly pixelated.
Original raw images in video camera are sharp.
What values should I use for bit_rate? Do I have to also set rc_max_rate?
What values should I use for global_quality? Do I have to set any flags to enable use of global_quality?
Is bit_rate versus global_quality an either/or situation? Or can both be useful in adjusting quality?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: 400kb is quite low for video bitrate

Comment: Some of your questions can't be answered because we don't know what encoder you're using.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: codec for MP4 output is H.264/MPEG-4 AVC as chosen by avformat_alloc_context_output2.

Comment: @szatmary: yes, thank you, I suspected the same, but FFmpeg sample source muxing.c, specifically intended to create an MP4 file, sets bit_rate to 400000. Can you suggest a value that will result in high quality video? Would that also require setting rc_max_rate?

Comment: Check your mp4, it's actually contains h264? Try to specify libx264

Comment: @bukkojot I am directly using the Windows DLLs provided by Zeranoe, i.e., avcodec-57.dll, avformat-57.dll, avutil-55.dll, swresample-2.dll and swscale-4.dll. I have a DLL of my own that performs a LoadLibrary for each of the Zeranoe DLLs then GetProcAddress for each needed entry point. Had a lot of trouble with the LIB files provided by Zeranoe; they linked just fine but generated "DLL not found" at run time, even though DLLs themselves absolutely positively were in same folder as EXE. How can I specify "libx264"?

Comment: You always can build everything what you need by youself, zeranoe provides cool script for it. But as I remember, libx264 already compiled in. You must specify "libx264" as codec name.

Comment: I have boosted bit_rate to 2000000 [2 million] and rc_max_rate as well and now MP4 quality is very good. Anyone aware of any reference or table suggesting what bit_rate's correspond to what quality?